# MySQL All-word search

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a simple question about MySQL ALL-Word search capability:

Is it possible to perform an ALL-WORD search in MySQL and make the order of the words matter? (apparently, the order of the words by default doesn't matter)

For example, let say I have this query:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM Person
WHERE MATCH (firstname, lastname)
      AGAINST ("+firstname +lastname" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I want the firstname to ALWAYS appear before the lastname in the results

How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you mean

```
I want the firstname to ALWAYS appear before the lastname in the results
```

This make no sense because based on your query all the records returned will match both firstname and lastname.

Anyway there isn't a score-word point system.
But maybe you can try the tilde operator to lower the relevance

> ~
>
> A leading tilde acts as a negation
>   operator, causing the word's
>   contribution to the row's relevance to
>   be negative. This is useful for
>   marking “noise” words. A row
>   containing such a word is rated lower
>   than others, but is not excluded
>   altogether, as it would be with the -
>   operator.

Comment: SELECT firstname, lastname FROM Person
WHERE MATCH (firstname, lastname)
      AGAINST ("+firstname +lastname" IN BOOLEAN MODE); will return reults like: "The firstname is blahblah and the lastname is blahblah" or "The lastname is blahblah and the firstname is blahblah". The order does not matter. Me I want the order to matter, I want the firstname to ALWAYS appear before the lastname. I know I can do this with EXACT word search, but I want to do it with All-word search.